# SonarQube failed to start on Windows

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am facing trouble to start the `SonarQube Server` as either a service or on its own.

(All commands being run as Administrator on Windows 10, with 64-bit JDK and JRE installled)

```
C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube\temp
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\jre\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\sonarqube\temp\conf\es
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:39 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2018.01.09 10:05:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

or

```
C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>InstallNTService.bat
wrapper  | SonarQube installed.

C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>StartNTService.bat
wrapper  | Starting the SonarQube service...
wrapper  | Waiting to start...
wrapper  | The SonarQube service was launched, but failed to start.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I assume the error is the same for both of the cases.

Comment: I had the same error when I was using a local user account to run the service and it wasn't a local administrator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I looked into the logs, and saw this in sonarqube\logs\es: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks`

I figured that was the issue, so I went to Task Manager and ended the Java task that was running.  Then I was able to run StartNTService.bat.  Not sure what the actual issue was, maybe the process didn't end correctly the first time I started it and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\sonarqube-8.9.3.48735\sonarqube-8.9.3.48735\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
```

I tried with the StartNTservice.bat file so many times then I ran the **StartSonar.bat** file in the same location.It started the sonarqube service in my windows 10 system